# Create folders based on file-content

Tags: bash, directory

I have txt file like this:

```
f1 3
f2 4
f3 2
```

I have to create folder (directory) in bash with name f1, and with 3 subfolders with random names, then folder with name f2, and with 4 subfolders with random names, etc.

I made the following attempt, but it is creating me only folders, without subfolders.

```
#!/bin/bash

dir=/home/bae/Desktop/egzamin/5
filename=$dir/nazwy.txt

cut -d " " -f 1 $fi
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are after is something like this:

```
while read -r dirname count; do
   mkdir -p "$dirname"
   for (( i=0; i < $count; ++i)); do mktemp -d -p "$dirname"; done
done < textfile
```

This reads your file lines by line, reading two arguments `dirname` and `count`. It will first make the parent directory and then run a loop to create the requested subdirectories using `mktemp`. Have a look at `man mktemp` for the various options to manipulate the naming of the subdirectories.

**note:** if there are possible "empty" lines or wrong entries in your textfile, you might want to incorporate the sanity checks from [Wiimm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54648188/8344060).

Answer (score 1):

```
while read dir count
do
    # some sanity checks
    [[ $dir = "" || $count = "" ]] && continue
    ((count<0)) && continue

    mkdir -p "$dir" # only needed for count==0
    for (( i=0; i<count; i++ ))
    do 
        mkdir -p "$dir/$RANDOM-$i"
    done
done < TEXTFILE
```

Comment: `$RANDOM` might fail! It could create already existing directories. Use `mktemp`.

Comment: Interesting fix (+1)

Answer (score 0):

```
<txt xargs -l sh -c 'mkdir "$1"; cd "$1"; mkdir $(seq "$2" | xargs -l sh -c "echo \$RANDOM")' --
```

- `<txt` - input the content from the file named `txt` onto standard input of the command
- `xargs -l` - run the command for each line passing the line as the arguments to the command
- `mkdir "$1"` - creates a directory and cd's into it from the first column of the file
- `seq "$2"` - outputs sequentially increasing numbers from 1 to the number in the second column passed as the second argument
- `xargs -l sh -c "echo \$RANDOM"` - just a shortcut for outputting a random number for each line of the input.
- `cd "$1"; mkdir $(....)` - creates the files inside the folder

Comment: `$RANDOM` might fail! It could create already existing directories.

Comment: Yes, however, you could imagine that there exists already a directory "$1" which already has a subdirectory "1".